# Error While Performing Bulk Operation on Multiple Containers in GridDB

Tags: griddb

I discovered that GridDB offers to perform bulk operations on different containers, which offers a great advantage to data analysts, as multiple projects can be combined to build a distinct project. It would help to offer more thorough research, analysis, and evidence
to back the hypotheses. Therefore, I compiled my two projects with their respective containers to search records and collect aggregated results to determine each car brand's sales. Below mentioned are their schemas:

```java
const name01 = new griddb.ContainerInfo({
    'name': "usedcaranalysis",
    'columnInfoList': [
      ["name", griddb.Type.STRING],
      ["Sales_ID", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["year", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["selling_price", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["km_driven", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["Region", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["State or Province", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["City", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["Country", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["fuel", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["seller_type", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["transmission", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["owner", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["mileage", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["engine", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["max_power", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["torque", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["seats", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["sold", griddb.Type.STRING]
    ],
    'type': griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, 'rowKey': true
});

const name02 = new griddb.ContainerInfo({
    'name': "gdpanalysis",
    'columnInfoList': [
      ["name", griddb.Type.STRING],
      ["Country", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["2010", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2011", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2012", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2013", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2014", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2015", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2016", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2017", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2018", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2019", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2020", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2021", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2022", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2023", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
    ],
    'type': griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, 'rowKey': true
});
```

Now I tried to perform a bulk search on them, using the [documentation](https://docs.griddb.net/GridDB_Java_API_Reference.html#sec-1-2-5) as follows:

```java
final List<String> containerNameList = Arrays.asList(
    "name01", "name02");
final List<String> keyList = Arrays.asList(
    "col01", "col02", "col03");

// Acquiring a GridStore instance
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("notificationAddress", args[0]);
props.setProperty("notificationPort", args[1]);
props.setProperty("clusterName", args[2]);
props.setProperty("user", args[3]);
props.setProperty("password", args[4]);
GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore(props);

// Creating a container information
ContainerInfo info = new ContainerInfo();
info.setType(ContainerType.COLLECTION);
info.setColumnInfoList(Arrays.asList(
    new ColumnInfo("Car_Name", GSType.STRING),
    new ColumnInfo("Country", GSType.STRING),
    new ColumnInfo("No_Of_Sold", GSType.INTEGER),
info.setRowKeyAssigned(true);

// Searching rows in bulk from multiple collections (Using queries)
List<Query<Row>> queryList = new ArrayList<Query<Row>>();
  for (Container<String, Row> container : containerList) {
    String tql = "select * where No_Of_Sold >= 100000";
    queryList.add(container.query(tql));
}

store.fetchAll(queryList);

for (int i = 0; i < queryList.size(); i++) {
  Query<Row> query = queryList.get(i);
  RowSet<Row> rs = query.getRowSet();
  while (rs.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rs.next();

    String Car_Name = row.getString(0);
    String Country = row.getString(2);
    Int No_Of_Sold = row.getInteger(3);

    System.out.println("Record[" + i + "]:" +
        " name=" + Car_Name +
        " country=" + Country +
        " count=" + No_Of_Sold 
  }
}
```

However, GridDB gave me the following error:

```
Error: Container 'name01' not found.
```

Although, as you can see above in my code, I have already defined the containers `name01` and `name02`. Additionally, I made a separate third container named, `info`, to store the result, but it did not help.

Kindly help in resolving the issue. Thank you in advance for helping me out.